# Manipulating matricies in Maxima (wx)

Tags: matrix, maxima

I want to do some simple matrix manipulations in wxMaxima. The problem I'm facing is that Maxima always provides answers in terms of the individual elements of matrices. Here's an example:

I want to expand
(A+B)(A+B)`
where A and B are 2x2 matricies. Then I want to see the output:

AA`+AB`+BA`+BB`,

but what I get is a matrix like:

[(b2+a2)^2+(b1+a1)^2   .......]

[..................................  .......]
(I've just put dots instead of entering all the elements)

So is there anyway to force Maxima to manipulate the matrices without looking at the elements inside them??

Thanks

Comment: You could use delayed evaluation, prefix all matrices with an apostrophe (`'`), but that still expands after simplification. [This](http://www.math.utexas.edu/pipermail/maxima/2009/015950.html) thread comes close to what you want.

Comment: So putting an apostrophe after part of an equation is supposed to stop Maxima from evaluating it?? It isn't working for me. I just get incorrect syntax errors...

Comment: Prefix means "place before", e.g. `'A . transpose('A)`.

Comment: Daaaaaaa, ok. Let me try that when I get home.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't fill in the matrices, and just declare them as nonscalar, you can get what you want:

```
(%i1) declare([A,B], nonscalar)$
      (A+B) . transpose(A+B);
      %, expand;

(%o2) (B+A) . (transpose(B)+transpose(A))
(%o3) B . transpose(B)+B . transpose(A)+A . transpose(B)+A . transpose(A)
```